# iterating through numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new in this so excuse my noob question.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(120, size=(10, 4))
x
```

output:

```
array([[ 69,  60,  86,  33],
       [ 11,  68, 104,  46],
       [ 62, 106,  15,  64],
       [ 96,  47,   3,  36],
       [ 82,  12, 110,   5],
       [ 12,  92,  44,  96],
       [ 67,   4,  71,  30],
       [ 19,  70,  91,  18],
       [ 70,  34, 115,  29],
       [108,  88,  22,  57]])
```

```
a = np.argmax(x, axis=1)
print("Index of maximum value of each row of the array is: ", a)
```

output:

```
Index of maximum value of each row of the array is:  [2 2 1 0 2 3 2 2 2 0]
```

Now I want to make list of the values of maximum numbers in each row. which should be

```
[86 104 106 96 110 96 71 91 115 108]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In the future, please start with your own research. I found that question by googling `numpy get max`. For more tips, see [ask]. BTW, if you read the documentation for [`np.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), it shows two different ways of getting the max value. Also, there's no iteration involved here, at least not at the Python level.

Comment: `x[np.arange(x.shape[0]), a]`.  The `arange` indexes the rows, `a` the columns, together they select one element from each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
np.max(x, axis=1)
```

This outputs:

```py
[ 86 104 106  96 110  96  71  91 115 108]
```